# Is there a function to find the count of each string for every column?

Tags: r

I have a task that seems easy, but after working on it for a few hours I've decided that I'm stumped.

I have a dataframe:

```
mydata <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
  rime   point   sound
  Y      Y       Y
  N      N       Y
  Y      Y       Y 
  NA     NA      NA
")
```

I would like my dataframe to look like this:

```
mydata <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
  standard   Y   N   NA  
  rime       2   1   1
  point      2   1   1
  sound      3   0   1
")
```

My first thought was to use `dplyr::count()`. I can get the correct numbers, but I have over 100 columns and don't want to call all of them by hand. Is there an R function that I could use to get the count I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. The key is to format you data to long, compute the desired summary (in your case you want the number of observations per groups). After that you can reshape again to wide in order to format the data as you want. Here the code using a `tidyverse` approach with the data you shared `mydata`:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
mydata %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  group_by(name,value) %>%
  summarise(N=n()) %>% ungroup() %>%
  group_by(name) %>% mutate(id=cur_group_id()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value,values_from=N) %>%
  select(-id) %>%
  replace(is.na(.),0)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   name [3]
  name      N     Y  `NA`
  <chr> <int> <int> <int>
1 point     1     2     1
2 rime      1     2     1
3 sound     0     3     1
```

Answer (score 4):

### xtabs

Using only base R we convert to long form using `stack` and then perform the frequency counting using `xtabs`.  To get it into the orientation shown in the question the resulting table is transposed.

```
t(xtabs(~., stack(mydata), addNA = TRUE))
##        values
## ind     N Y <NA>
##   rime  1 2    1
##   point 1 2    1
##   sound 0 3    1
```

### table

This variation also works and gives a similar result.  (The data portions of both are the same but the class of the `xtabs` solution is `c("xtabs", "table")` and it has a `call` attribute whereas the one below has the `"table"` class.)

```
t(table(stack(mydata), useNA = "ifany"))
```

### tapply

We can use `tapply` giving a matrix output.  We first change the NA's to ordinary levels since `tapply` would remove those NAs.

```
s <- transform(stack(mydata), values = addNA(values))
t(tapply(rownames(s), s, length, default = 0))
```

### pivot_*

Using tidyr we can convert to long form and back to wide form giving a tibble result:

```
library(tidyr)

mydata %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  pivot_wider(name, names_from = "value", values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)
## # A tibble: 3 x 4
##   name      Y     N  `NA`
##   <chr> <int> <int> <int>
## 1 rime      2     1     1
## 2 point     2     1     1
## 3 sound     3     0     1
```

### ctable

`ctable` in the summarytools package has many arguments to customnize the output.  Here is the default output.

```
library(summarytools)

with(stack(mydata), ctable(ind, values))
```

giving:

```
Cross-Tabulation, Row Proportions  
ind * values  
Data Frame: stack  

------- -------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -------------
          values           N           Y        <NA>         Total
    ind                                                           
   rime            1 (25.0%)   2 (50.0%)   1 (25.0%)    4 (100.0%)
  point            1 (25.0%)   2 (50.0%)   1 (25.0%)    4 (100.0%)
  sound            0 ( 0.0%)   3 (75.0%)   1 (25.0%)    4 (100.0%)
  Total            2 (16.7%)   7 (58.3%)   3 (25.0%)   12 (100.0%)
------- -------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -------------
```

### Update

Have added additional approaches.

Comment: Thank for this! This has convinced me that I should get better at writing base R (I rely mostly on tidyverse).

Comment: @Mishalb and yet you accept the sausage of the solution over this one.